# How to access the ItemsWrapGrid panel which is placed inside the ItemsPanelTemplate?

Tags: c#, uwp, itemscontrol, itemspaneltemplate, winui-3

I used **ItemsControl** bounded to the ItemsSource collection, and I arranged items using the **ItemsWrapGrid** control panel. But ItemsWrapGrid panel was placed inside the ItemsPanelTemplate, so I couldn't access that element in the code behind c#.

I have tried with **VisualTreeHelper** method to find the panel in a visualtree. and doesn't retrieves the element when using inside the items panel template.

```
<ItemsControl
     x:Name="itemsControl"
     ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
     ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding GalleryItemCollection}"
     SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}">
       <itemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <ItemsWrapGrid x:Name="itemsWrapGrid"
                      ItemHeight="{Binding Path=ItemHeight}"
                      ItemWidth="{Binding Path=ItemWidth}"
                      MaximumRowsOrColumns="{Binding Path=MaximumColumnCount}"
                      Orientation="Horizontal" />
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </itemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   </itemsControl>
```

Can someone please help me how to access the **itemswrapGrid** code element behind c#?

Comment: From where and when are you trying to access the `ItemsWrapGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `Loaded` event handler to the `ItemsWrapGrid` control and assign the sender to a member variable, and then you could access the `ItemsWrapGrid` control by the member variable.

For example:

```
//MainPage.xaml
<ItemsWrapGrid x:Name="itemsWrapGrid" Background="Red" Loaded="itemsWrapGrid_Loaded"
                      ……>  </ItemsWrapGrid>


//MainPage.xaml.cs
private ItemsWrapGrid _itemsWrapGrid;

private void itemsWrapGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _itemsWrapGrid = sender as ItemsWrapGrid;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _itemsWrapGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

Comment: If your problem is resolved, it is better if you could mark the answer so that poeple with the same problems could find a solution quickly.

Comment: I was having a nice time trying to access content inside ItemsPanel.. This helped me, I also put the event handlers in there _itemsWrapGrid.SomeEvent += ...

Answer (score 0):

In codebehind

```
(ItemsWrapGrid)itemsControl.ItemsPanelRoot
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**